# Notice message about $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']

Tags: php

I have self written CMS which does not return correct user's IP address with the following:

```
define("USER_IP", $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
```

It gives me the following notice:

```
Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR in /var/www/p00000/data/www/domain.ru/core/maincore.php on line 30
```

and line 20 = to the line define("USER_IP"...

A few question:

- What should I do to get rid of this notice message?
- How can I properly get user's IP address?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR are usually just set by proxies. So if the user is not using a proxy HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR will not be set. And that error you get is that it isn't set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){
   define("USER_IP", $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']); 
} else {
  define("USER_IP", $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); 
 ...
```

Comment: I already tried it, but the interesting part is: what would you put on else statement? That I am not going to define it? then If I don't define it, variable USER_IP is not going to work on some functions included into CMS.

Comment: Ok , your original question isn't very clear.  you could use $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR) (edit made to my answer)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /var/www/p00000/data/www/domain.ru/core/maincore.php on line 30

Comment: My code is missing a quote, Are you just copy and pasting without understanding what you are doing?

Comment: no, I know that there is a missing quote, but I still receive this error.

Comment: I think you should have enough to go on .. hope it works out.

Comment: Here is the right code: 

There are a few mistakes you mistakes you did:

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
   define("USER_IP", $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']); 
} else {